# Where to find list of behaviours/rules of Stack Exchange

Tags: discussion, badges, rules, hidden-features

Well, I know this is weird question. Recently I upvoted some answers, and I get a tooltip saying "You haven't been upvoted a question for a while. Questions need upvote too". It was nice to get it. But if I am correct there are many such behavioural things sprinkled in the whole Stack Exchange user experience. It might not exactly be the hints like above, but may be some other rules that run behind the scene.

For example,

1. Rules of badges, when you get which badge
2. You cannot downvote someone straight on many answers

etc.

Is there any post where I can get such behaviour / rules / functions done/followed by Stack Exchange network? I know some of these can be found on [help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/) page like badges, but then I guess it does not list other behaviours...

Answer (score 3):

Here on Meta, there is the **[FAQ for Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7931/307988)**

The FAQ has a lot of useful information on how Stack Exchange works. It's community curated and constantly changing with edits from the community. The fact that it is maintained by regular users here means you get the information from the point of the view of regular users. It does also mean the information can be out of date or not 100% accurate though.

Most child metas will have an [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) too, so have a look for that (and meta in general) if you're interested in site-specific policies and issues.

Then there is the [**Help Center**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help)

The Help Center is available on every site and maintained by moderators and staff so can be more reliable. It's useful for new users who are interested in the basics of how Stack Exchange works.

If you have a specific query that isn't covered elsewhere you can [ask a question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). Either here (if your question is relevant to more than a single site, or on a specific site's meta if your question is only relevant to that site). Make sure to [search first](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search) as it's likely your question has already been asked and answered.

Comment: Does those linked pages anywhere contain information about the fact that no one can upvote/downvote someones answers straight multiple times? Just want to know if they contain all facts which might not be needed by community to know first hand and which is silently enforced by stack exchange behind the scenes. (And also list of subtle pop ups displayed by stackexchange in different scenarios as I noted in the start of my question, though I feel its very unlikely these to be listed anywhere)

Comment: You mean serial voting? If so yes... see [What is serial voting and how does it affect me?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126829/307988)

Comment: As for “subtle popups” I would suspect they are mentioned in context, rather than here being an actual list of popups